# Display text according to the value of react select

Tags: reactjs, state, react-select

I would like to display a different text according to the value selected in my react-select. handlechange time is working fine, my problem is when I try to retrieve the value in my p tag to display different text depending on the value

My code:

```
const timeSlots = [
    {
        value: 0,
        label: 'what is your choice ?'
    },
    {
        value: 1,
        label: 'choice 1'
    },
    {
        value: 2,
        label: 'choice 2'
    },
    {
        value: 3,
        label: 'choice 3'
    },
    {
        value: 4,
        label: 'choice 4'
    }
]

class WidgetBooking extends Component {

    state ={
        selectedOption: null,
    }
    
    handleChangeTime = (selectedOption) => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
        console.log(selectedOption);
    }

    
    
    render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                    <div className="time-slots padding-bottom-30px">
                        <Select
                            value={selectedOption}
                            onChange={this.handleChangeTime}
                            placeholder="what is your choice ?"
                            options={timeSlots}
                        />
                    </div>
                    {selectedOption === '1' &&
                        <p className="d-block widget-title">756, 23 $</p>
                    }
                    {selectedOption === '2' &&
                        <p className="d-block widget-title">865, 23 $</p>
                    }
                    {selectedOption === '3' &&
                        <p className="d-block widget-title">756, 23 $</p>
                    }
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

I would like to display a different price in a p tag, like show above.
Thanks for your help

Comment: "my problem is when I try to retrieve the value in my p tag to display different text depending on the value"  Exactly, what is the problem?

Comment: The display of my text in the p tag according to the value chosen in select

Comment: currently when I choose a value in my select, nothing is displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two issues here:

1. confusion between an option and the option's value
2. confusion between `string` and `number`

#### Option vs. Value

What do you see when you call `console.log(selectedOption)` inside `handleChangeTime`?  I see a complete option object that looks like `{value: 2, label: "choice 2"}`.  That's what you are saving to `this.state.selectedOption`.  But when you compare it in your `render`, you are expecting `this.state.selectedOption` to be a numeric string like `'1'` or `'2'` -- not an object.

Either one is fine to `setState` with, but you have to be consistent about what it is or else you will never have a match.  If you want to keep `handleChangeTime` the same, then your render checks need to look like `selectedOption?.value === 1`.  If you want to keep your `render()` the same, then you need to be setting the state like `this.setState({ selectedOption: selectedOption.value.toString() })`.  That `toString()` brings us to the next issue.

#### Number vs. String

When you are comparing values, the `number` `1` and the `string` `'1'` are not the same.  If you were dealing with the DOM `select` element directly, you would likely wind up with `string` values.  But the `react-select` package calls `onChange` with the option in the same format that you provided it.  In this case, your `value` property is a `number`.  Again it's consistency that's important.  I recommend that you keep it a `number` everywhere and change your render conditions from `selectedOption === '1'` to `selectedOption === 1`.

Corrected Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const timeSlots = [ /* ... */ ];

class WidgetBooking extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null // will be a number or null
  };

  handleChangeTime = ({ value }) => { // destructure to get just the value
    this.setState({ selectedOption: value });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div className="time-slots padding-bottom-30px">
          <Select
            value={selectedOption}
            onChange={this.handleChangeTime}
            placeholder="what is your choice ?"
            options={timeSlots}
          />
        </div>
        {selectedOption === 1 && (
          <p className="d-block widget-title">756, 23 $</p>
        )}
        {selectedOption === 2 && (
          <p className="d-block widget-title">865, 23 $</p>
        )}
        {selectedOption === 3 && (
          <p className="d-block widget-title">756, 23 $</p>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```